# Vi editor: What's the fastest way to delete multiple rows in a file?

Tags: vim, vi

I'd like to use the Vi editor to delete multiple rows in a file. Please give me idea or suggestion.

My goal is like this:

Before:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
.
.
29
30
.
.
```

After;

```
1
10
20
30
40
.
.
```

Comment: how do you chose the rows to delete ? Do you wan to leave one row every 10 ?

Comment: You can delete ranges of lines with `:[range]d` for example `:3,5d` deletes lines three through five (inclusively).

Comment: There is also [vi.stackexchange](http://vi.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @R Ketkaew - Are you trying to remove a list of numbers or are they rows? Could you please update your question to clarify ?

Comment: I know you're asking about Vi, but you can do with GNU Sed, too: `gsed -n '1p; 0~10p'`

Comment: @DarkHeart
Thank you again for your help and worry. 
I used and adapted a "%norm 9ddj" to perform that thing which I want and it also works for me.
However, I have to duplicate the data in row 1 before using norm command, otherwise the first of 9 rows (including 1st row) would be deleted anyway.

Cheers,
R. Ketkaew

Comment: @ssdecontrol Many thanks, I'd try that command for next time.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you mean you want to keep every 10th line and delete the rest:

```
%norm 9ddj
```

Explanation:

`%` whole file

`norm` execute the following commands in "normal mode"

`9dd` delete 9 lines

`j` move down one line (i.e. keep it)

**note:** this deletes the first row.

Adapted from http://www.rayninfo.co.uk/vimtips.html

---

Or using the global command:

- Duplicate the first line <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>
- `:g/^/+ d9`

Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946738/vim-how-to-delete-every-second-row

---

Or you could use `awk`:

```
%!awk 'NR \% 10 == 0 || NR == 1'
```

Comment: The awk command works for me. I always thought awk required a minimum of one block `{...}`. good to know you don't. It's the first non-trivial awk command I've got working!

Comment: @the_velour_fog the block _is_ required. if you don't write one, AWK will behave as if you had written `{ print $0 }`

Comment: @RKetkaew Which of the options did you use? If a response solves your question, please click on the tick to mark it as the answer.

Comment: @underscore_d Hi, I used a command suggested from DarkHeart. Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 12):

```
:2,$v/0$/d
```

deletes the lines that don't end in `0` starting from the second one.

Comment: This, this is the clever solution.  I'd just add an explanation that `2,$` is the range, and `v/0$/d` the `g!` command.  Where `0$` is the regex and `d` the ex command that will be run on all lines that do not match.